# How to stop program from closing after switch statements

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Hi I am currently making a basic program with a four option menu. The following code works fine (I still have work to do on the first three options but i will try and do this on my own) the only problem is after an option is selected and it breaks the program closes. I was wondering how I could make it so that the program returns to the menu after an option is selected, and the program only closes when the user selects "4". Thanks!

```
cout << "Correct login details entered!" << "" << endl;
cout << "1. Transfer an amount" <<endl;
cout << "2. List recent transactions"<<endl;
cout << "3. Display account details and current balance"<<endl;
cout << "4. Quit" << endl;
cout << "Please enter menu number"<<endl;
cin >> selection;


switch(selection)
{
case 1: 
cout << "You have choosen to transfer an amount" << endl;
cout << "How much do you wish to transfer from the shop account?"<<endl;
cin >> B;
cout << B << endl;
break;


case 2:
cout << "Here are you're recent transactions" <<endl;
break;

case 3:
cout << "The account names is:" << name << endl;
cout << "The account number is:" << number << endl;
cout << "The current balance is" << endl; //Need to get cuurent balance still
break;

case 4:
return 0;
break;

default:
cout << "Ooops, invalid selection!" << endl;
break;
```

Comment: Add a loop around your 'menu' code

Comment: Well, you could start by trying to write a small program that reads inputs until it gets a 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: I assume you are running a console application inside visual studio? And after main() exits the application closes the window. Edit: Oh I see you want a loop around your switch.

Comment: post the entire program and you will get more precise help. short answer: put a loop around it: `do { } while(selection != 4);`

Comment: @yngum I'm tempted to flag that as "rude or offensive" -- be nice to beginners! ;-)

Comment: `break` is redundant in case label 4, by the way. `return` supercedes `break`. Some compilers will warn you for doing this if you set them to be extremely verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do{
    cout << "Correct login details entered!" << "" << endl;
    cout << "1. Transfer an amount" <<endl;
    cout << "2. List recent transactions"<<endl;
    cout << "3. Display account details and current balance"<<endl;
    cout << "4. Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter menu number"<<endl;
    cin >> selection;

    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1: 
    //... 

    case 2:
    //...

    case 3:
    //...

    case 4:
    //...

    default:
    //...

    }
while(selection != 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while ( true )
{
   cout << "1. Transfer an amount" <<endl;
   // ...

   switch(selection)
   {
   case 1: 
   // ...
   } // end of switch
}
```